# ROS Answers SE migration: Ros serial

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All
I am trying to run the Time and TF tutorial but i get the following error

```
TimeTF.cpp: In function ‘void loop()’: 
TimeTF:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘unsigned char*’
TimeTF:26: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘unsigned char*’ 
TimeTF:32: error: ‘class ros::NodeHandle’ has no member named ‘now’
```

I'm using ros_electric ubuntu 10.4 32 bit aurdino uno and aurdino 22

the other examples work fine

peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11199/ros-serial/) by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Peter,

I think that the problem is that the electric release is actually an older version of rosserial.  We broke that API a little while ago and updated the documentation on the website to reflect newest code.  Could you try pulling rosserial from the repo and using it?

Just do :

hg clone  https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg rosserial

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2011-09-15**:
Thanks it works now just a note do a rosmake before copying ros_lib it will save a few headaches